# The "pixels between the eyes" rating of opencv's facial recignition?

Tags: opencv, emgucv, face-recognition

Ya about says it all.

And if anyone has, can post, or point me to a comprehensive list of facial recognition solutions, with the pixel between the eyes ratings, and pricing/licensing when concerning commercial offerings it would be ***really*** great!

I keep expecting to find one of those wiki pages full of side by side comparisons...

Comment: I do facial recognition and I've never seen "pixel between the eyes" used as a rating. Usually when you're talking about facial recognition you talk about it using ROC curves, and accuracy on public data sets. I googled "pixel(s) between the eyes" and THIS POST was the top hit. Honestly pixels between the eyes sounds like a marketing tactic (WORKS WITH JUST 3 PIXELS BETWEEN THE EYES!)

Comment: If you're concerned about the algorithm working on really small images, go find a dataset that measures this aspect of facial recognition (normal sized gallery images and tiny probe images), and see how OpenCV scores.

Comment: You havent heard of pixels between the eyes? Perhaps is a marketing tactic, but pittpatt states on their site that they have min 15 PBE, if you ask Luxand they have 40, and L1ID's Facit SDK boasts 10!

Comment: I was going to test it next week when I got back to work, I was just curious as to whether someone had already.

Comment: @expelledboy: mine can do 0 pixels! Of course, the accuracy is about 12%, but the important thing is that it can DO it. I'm telling you that metric is useless (by itself). Show me a product that can do 10 pixels with 90% accuracy and a low FA / FR rate, and then I'll get excited.

Comment: I understand. Could you direct me to a SDK that performs well at low resolutions with a once of developers licence?

Comment: @expelledboy: sorry, I don't know of any. The product I work on is for low-light images, so I don't look around too much for low-res stuff. I've upvoted your question though, because when asked like that it's a very good question.